# Unable to pass script with two parameters at a time

Tags: loadrunner

I am working on HP-Load runner 12.02. I have two parameters say(P1 n P2) if i substitute two parameters at a time in my script it is failing. If I ran with any of one parameter I am able to pass the script.

There is no relation between these two parameters LB and RB are completely different for these two parameters.

**EDITED1:**
My first parameter was IP Address to make sure my code will work for another systems also and one more parameter was some dynamic value which is randomly generated by server.

**EDITED2:**
If I use these two parameters at a time I am getting error for parameter two which is a dynamic value.
Error message: Check whether LB/RB existed properly.

If i use only parameter two(Dynamic value) I am able to pass the script in my machine.

Comment: Please edit question and add a small code snippet demonstrating what you are doing (what works, what doesn't).

Comment: No, I said "edit question"! Do not post code in comments... And maybe you can read some of this to help you understand how things work here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks #James 
I tried it it is not working can you please tell me how lr_eval_string() helps in my case.

Comment: If you can use either parameter successfully, but not both, then there is a chance that you need to be explicit in your conversion from a label to a value, so in your code instead of just including the curly braced parameter names in quotes, include them inside of an explicit conversion, such as ....lr_eval_string("..{param1}..."), lr_eval_string("...{param2}..."),..